# Split SQL table concatenated column into row

Tags: sql, split, amazon-redshift

I have a Redshift database table as follows:

| id | feedbackdate | feedback | hashtags |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2023-05-20 | this is good | #good,#useful |

I want to transform it to the following so that I can pass it to Tableau to visualize and filter the feedback by each individual hashtag:

| id | feedbackdate | feedback | hashtags |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2023-05-20 | this is good | #good |
| 123 | 2023-05-20 | this is good | #useful |

What should be the SQL statement look like?

Comment: So in summary, you want to tranform the hashtags into rows, how it should be stored anyway... so just fix the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
  SELECT
  t.id,
  t.feedbackdate,
  t.feedback,
  '#' || TRIM(s.value) AS hashtags
FROM
  your_table AS t
CROSS JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      SPLIT_PART(hashtags, ',', seq) AS value
    FROM
      your_table,
      generate_series(1, regexp_count(hashtags, ',') + 1) AS seq
  ) AS s;
```

The REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE function splits the hashtags column into multiple rows based on the comma (,) delimiter.

Comment: Thanks so much for writing back to me! When execute the SQL statement it said syntax error at or near "select" (the select within the lateral statement). Any reason why?

Comment: @RaymondChau  It seems that the version of Amazon Redshift you are using does not support subqueries inside the LATERAL join. I updated the query

Answer (score 0):

REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE is not supported in AWS Redshift. Details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html)

You can use Redshift [JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY_ELEMENT_TEXT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY_ELEMENT_TEXT.html) function to retrieve the values. Use it in conjunction with recursive query and it should give you the expected output. Here's the SQL;

**NOTE: Make sure to replace <<your_tbl>> with the correct table name**

```
with
recursive NS(n) as
(
select 0
union all
select n+1 from NS where n < (select max(regexp_count(r.hashtags,’,’)) from your_tbl r )
)
select
r.id ,
r.feedbackdate,
r.feedback,
JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY_ELEMENT_TEXT(r.hashtags,NS.n) as hashtag
from
your_tbl r , NS as NS
where
NS.n < regexp_count(r.hashtags,’,’);
```